# How to add a blank spaces before and after the content inside a layer?

Tags: html

The next code trims the blank spaces before and after the text:

```
<div>  foo  </div>
```

So, How to add blank spaces there?

Comment: Where? Where do you want to add white spaces?

Comment: @AfzaalAhmadZeeshan - Before and after 'foo'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
&nbsp;
```

This is a space in html.

Comment: Happens to the best ;)